# Can we schedule StackDriver Logging to export log?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am new to [Google Cloud StackDriver Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/) and as per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quotas) StackDriver stores the Data Access audit logs for 30 days. Also mentioned on the same page, that Size of a log entry is limited to 100KB. 
I am aware of the fact that the logs can be exported [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/) using [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/quickstart-sdk) as well as using [Logging Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/) in many languages (we prefer Python). 
I have two questions related to the exporting the logs, which are:

1. Is there any way in StackDriver to schedule something similar to a task or cronjob that keeps exporting the Logs in the Google Cloud storage automatically after a fixed interval of time?
2. What happens to the log entries which are larger than 100KB. I assume they get truncated. Is my assumption correct? If yes, is there any way in which we can export/view the full(which is not at all truncated) Log entry?

Comment: For the scheduled logging ... perhaps look into the Stackdriver logging "sinks" capability.  One can can figure a sink such that log records are automatically externalized on a rolling basis as and when new log records arrive.  That would seem to obviate the need for scheduled logging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any way in StackDriver to schedule something similar to a
>   task or cronjob that keeps exporting the Logs in the Google Cloud
>   storage automatically after a fixed interval of time?

Stackdriver supports exporting log data via `sinks`. There is no schedule that you can set as everything is automatic. Basically, the data is exported `as soon as possible` and you have no control over the amount exported at each sink or the delay between exports. I have never found this to be an issue. Logging, by design, is not to be used as a real-time system. The closest is to sink to PubSub which has a couple of second delay (based upon my experience).

There are two methods to export data from Stackdriver:

1. Create an export sink. Supported destinations are BigQuery, Cloud Storage and PubSub. The log entries will be written to the destination automatically. You can then use tools to process the exported entries. This is the recommended method.
2. Write your own code in Python, Java, etc. to read the log entries and do what you want with them. Scheduling is up to you. This method is manual and requires your management of schedule and destination.

> What happens to the log entries which are larger than 100KB. I assume
>   they get truncated. Is my assumption correct? If yes, is there any way
>   in which we can export/view the full(which is not at all truncated)
>   Log entry?

Entries that exceed the max size of an entry cannot be written to Stackdriver. The API call that attempts to create the entry will fail with an error message similar to (Python error message):

```
400 Log entry with size 113.7K exceeds maximum size of 110.0K
```

This means that entries that are too large will be discarded unless the writer has logic to handle this case.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation of stack driver logging the whole process is automatic. Export sink to google cloud storage is slower than the Bigquery and Cloud sub/pub. [link for the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/)

I recently used the export sink to the big query, which is better than cloud pub/sub in case if you don't want to use other third-party application for log analysis. For Bigquery sink needs dataset where do you want to store the log entries. I noticed that sink create bigquery table on a timestamp basis in the bigquery dataset.

One more thing if you want to query timestamp partitioned tables check this link

[Legacy SQL Functions and Operators](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#tablewildcardfunctions)